# OWB deploy hangs. Deployment never fhinishes

Tags: oracle-warehouse-builder

My Oracle Warehouse Builder was not able to deploy anything to the repository. There is no error message, and the deployed job is seen as running, but never finishes:

```
Locking : COUNTRY
Locking : COUNTRY  (12%)
Validating : COUNTRY  (12%)
Validating : COUNTRY  (25%)
Generating : COUNTRY  (25%)
Storing validation messages for: COUNTRY  (25%)
Storing validation messages for: COUNTRY  (37%)
Storing validation messages for: COUNTRY  (50%)
Storing validation messages for: COUNTRY  (50%)
Created Deployment for FATCA_DEV_LOCATION (Create) - 0  (50%)
  (50%)
```

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that the Control Center Manager uses a wrong password for the repository owner (usually OWBSYS), or this user is locked. Unlock the user and/or change the password in control center.

To change the password in the control center use following steps: http://gerardnico.com/wiki/owb/repository_owner.